# Get group of object s from Django model

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I've created an one model, it contains consulting date, time and locations.

I want to group the data by date, time and location by using Django ORM models.The result should be 
,[group of objects],[group of objects]] and each group contains[,]contains [,].

How can i achieve this result.